# Mavericks theme for Yosemite

Tags: macos, themes

I have to admit I don't really like the new design of OS X Yosemite, and I would like to get the good old Mavericks theme on the current Yosemite install.

Is this possible?

Comment: Themes seem to be like fads, and it is slightly rude that new OS versions don't give you the option to switch to previous themes.

Answer (score 1):

Not fully.

You can swap icons with [LiteIcon](http://www.freemacsoft.net/liteicon/) but not the overall theme, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable transparency by going to System Preferences > Accessibility > Display > Reduce Transparency

That may help you a little, in addition to changing back the icons as previously answered.